# CSS - text flow and centering

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an events app using Rails. On my index page each event is represented by a relevant image upon which the event title and date are transposed upon it. Like this -

[image: When titles are succinct...]

Ideally, I would want a user to input a title for their event which is 'to the point'/ 'succinct' however there's no real way I can control this nor would I want to. When I try and input an overly long title this happens -

[image: When titles are too long...]

I need the text to flow and for the title (and date) to be absolutely centred in the middle of the image.At the moment its breaking (as shown below) and clinging to the left.This is my relevant code I have at the moment -

**events.index.html.erb**

```
<ul>

                    <% @events.each do |event| %>
                <li class="events"> 
                        <%= link_to (image_tag event.image.url), event, id: "image" %>
                    <div class="text">  
                        <h2><%= link_to event.title, event %></h2>
                        <h3><%= link_to event.date.strftime('%A, %d %b %Y'), event %></h3>
                </li>       
                    <% end %>
                    </div>

            </ul>
```

**events.css.scss**

```
  li.events { 
    width: 350px; 
    height: 350px; 
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative; 

}

li.events img { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    border-radius: 20px;





}

div.text  { 


    padding: 25px; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100px;
    left: auto;



}

div.text a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FF69B4;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;    
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: invert(10px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;


}
```

I'm using the bootstrap gem but not sure whether this is relevant for this issue. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Try to add `text-align:center;` to `div.text`.

Comment: That's not quite getting there. I'm still getting the weird overlap for long titles with the abrupt break and some titles are centred, some aren't. haven't got a clue why...

Comment: Have you tried to set a `height / line-height` ? As I see the overlap occurs only in the title, so `line-height` could solve it.

Comment: No I haven't, where do i set that? I assumed this had more to do with text flow, am I wrong?

Comment: Logically should be set for `div.text a`, but just in case you could try it for `div.text` too after that. I guess it has to do with the fact that when text goes to another line, it doesn't "know" there is a padding (since it's inside the same tag) and goes straight below the letters. I'm not a guru, but should be like this.

Comment: And do you set it by number of pixels?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123451/discussion-between-denea-novac-and-mike-whitehead).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do that effect, and I found many tutorials that help me. Unfortunately the `border-radius` like that I found nothing usefull. **But**, on the other hand, the spaces on the begin and end of the line, I fixed it:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/s112Lao0/

As you can see, with out `border-radius`. But there is a nice `padding`.

Sources:

https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/

http://geoffmuskett.com/text-with-background-padding-on-the-end-of-each-line-and-a-gap-between-lines/

[https://fiddle.jshell.net/s112Lao0/](http://thany.nl/apps/BoxShadows/)

I hope that this will help . :)

Comment: So, basically, the border-radius line break is unfixable?

Comment: I've looked to implement the geoff muskett code but I'm still getting it clinging to the left with no border all the way round??

Comment: **Answering the first question:** Yep! To apply this effect the css must "see" the two lines as differents elements, but it is not, it is only one. The maximum  I could do, was apply that 'padding' :/  But if someone have a wonderful idea, my code is up there, feel free to update it :)

Comment: **Answering the second question:** Your `main-box` div must have a padding. In my example I applied `padding: 30px;`.